# Вычисление позиции элемента работает некорректно

Tags: jquery

Есть два абсолютно позицонированных элемента, которые нужно располагать наравне с верхом блока, положение (отступ сверху) которого при ресайзе окна меняется.

Использую вот такой вот скрипт

```
function determineModalArrowsPosition() {
    var offsetTop = $('.slick-active .modal-slider-bottom-text').position().top;

    $('.j-modal-slider-prev, .j-modal-slider-next').css({'top': offsetTop + 200 + 'px'});
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    determineModalArrowsPosition();
});
```

но с ним элементы смещаются. но куда-то неправильно, не так, как надо. При этом если, например, открыть окно разработчика(F12) и чуть поменять высоту окна, то эти элементы сразу становятся туда, куда нужно. В чем дело и как это поправить, чтобы оно работало?

**АПД.**
Всё понятно, так работало, потому что событие ресайз окна отслеживается сразу когда оно начинается, а не когда завершается, поэтому вычислялось некорректно. Вот с таким кодом заработало.

```
var delay = (function () {
    var timer = 0;
    return function (callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();


function determineModalArrowsPosition() {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        delay(function () {
            var offsetTop = $('.slick-active .modal-slider-bottom-text').position().top;
            $('.j-modal-slider-prev, .j-modal-slider-next').css({
                'top': offsetTop + 200 + 'px'
            });
        }, 50);

    });
    $(window).resize();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оформлю корректный вариант как ответ:

```
var delay = (function () {
    var timer = 0;
    return function (callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();


function determineModalArrowsPosition() {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        delay(function () {
            var offsetTop = $('.slick-active .modal-slider-bottom-text').position().top;
            $('.j-modal-slider-prev, .j-modal-slider-next').css({
                'top': offsetTop + 200 + 'px'
            });
        }, 50);

    });
    $(window).resize();
}
```